# How to do clutter removal in this data

Tags: matlab

I have an excel data sheet that I have plotted in the Matlab as the x-y axis. The y-axis signals have all tangled upon. please see the image for this.
These tangled signals have a high peak for a small duration. I want to perform a clutter removal method here in which only the high peak of the signal remains and rest becomes zero.
I look online and found that if I calculate the mean of each signal and then divide it by the number of signals, hence, calculating the average. Now, this average signal subtracted by each previous signal will give the only high peak area of the signal.
I'm not sure how to do it in the Matlab.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

### Method:

[image]

---

### My Graph and Progress:

[image: plot]

---

### Desired Output/Result:

[image: like this]

---

### Data/Excel Spreadsheets:

Each of the 51 signals has 12 samples respectively.

[image: data]

[image: Excel Sample Data of 51 Signals]

---

### Data from Excel Spreadsheets Plotted in MATLAB:

[image]

Comment: At the moment your question is unclear. Please provide a minimal example of your problem, also show us what you've tried and explain why it does not produce the desired results.

Comment: @obchardon Please see the attached images.

Comment: There are two methods that I could think of which are thresholding the noise or applying a windowing function that can be implemented using standard for-loops.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Thankyou so much for your reply. As you can see in the image "data" it has 12 rows and 52 columns. When I take mean of the data it changes into 1x52. If I again take mean of this then it gives one number. I went with single value of mean and followed your code. I put " sample = random_Single(:,i) there, as I want all rows. The out group is not what I want. Please help

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava Are the 12 signals tests of the same signal or are they completely different? If they're recorded values of the same signal from doing multiple tests using one mean would be best.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Actually these are 52 signals. 1st block is their range they are varying in. I plotted the excel sheet as 1st column -xaxis, and then column 2:51 (signals)-yaxis.

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava Could you post the Excel file it would make it easier for me test.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 I Could post it here but I dont think stackoverflow allows us to do that. Does it? Alternatively,  I can email you.

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava maybe posting a link to a GitHub repository would work.

Comment: @MichaelTr7  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OlytsmEvyasCPQS-EMmYm5JSO1RcY2b4/view?usp=sharing    ..... googledrive link. Thankyou

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava With only 12 samples per signal, there's little noise/clutter-reduction that can be done. Out of curiosity where did you obtain the signal data from? A higher fidelity signal sampled at a higher rate could be more practical.

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava I've updated the question to add a little more clarity feel free to remove it if you don't find it useful.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Yes, I understand the 12 samples aren't enough for one signal. These are antenna's reflection coefficients. I will try to get more samples for each signal. However, could you just tell me how clutter removal will be done in data like this? If i follow your code how will I do this? If i take a mean of the data it will give mean of each signal that will make the data 12x52 to 1x52, is that correct? if yes, how will i compare it with the threshold?

Comment: @ I'll update the code right now to work for your case. Find the mean for each of the 52 signals. Then for each signal set values that deviate only a little from the average to the mean.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 okay thankyou much :)

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava Alright, it's updated the only thing you'll need to change is the Margin variable depending on how much thresholding you want. Unfortunately, this will only work well with more sample data. I suggest looking into windowing if you cannot collect enough sample data. Here's the modified Excel sheet and MATLAB file: https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Noise_Removal

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Thankyou soo much. I really appreciate the effort. Yes, I will try to collect more data for the signals. This might work better then.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Hello Michael. Have a similar problem again. Saw your code, I have some doubts if you have some free time.

Comment: @DeepshikhaBhargava What is your question? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Thankyou so much for your reply. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ijydePfSCneR3vQUN0MMCFRJerwwAtHc?usp=sharing ..  Please see these files. So, this time I have (or at least I think I have) enough data to perform clutter removal. I want to omit positive as well as negative data outside a threshold value. Last time when we discussed you helped me with a code that gives a resultant signal only in positive values, but I also want -ve. I tried a bunch of codes but that doesn't seem to give the desired result. Would you please look at the files I shared here? Thank you so much.

Comment: I think this would better suited as a new question.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Okay posting it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by thresholding the signal. First, find the mean then create a variable with a noise threshold value. Then I would filter any value that falls within the range [mean-threshold,mean+threshold] and set it to the mean (alternatively you can set it to zero as stated in your question).

The `Margin` variable will control how much removal is done.

```
%Importing table data and changing data to array type%
Excel_Table_Data = readtable('stackoverflow.xlsx');
All_Signal_Data = table2array(Excel_Table_Data);

%Grabbing the first column as the sample indices%
Sample_Index = All_Signal_Data(:,1);

%Deleting the first column of the Signal_Data array corresponding to the
%sample indices%
All_Signal_Data(:,1) = [];


%Array to store each signal's mean value%
Number_Of_Signals = 51;
Mean_Array = zeros(1,Number_Of_Signals);

%Evaluating the mean of the 51 signals respectively%
for Signal_Number = 1: +1: Number_Of_Signals
Mean_Array(1,Signal_Number) = mean(All_Signal_Data(:,Signal_Number));   
end 

Margin = 0.00;

%Thresholding the signal%
for Signal_Number = 1: +1: Number_Of_Signals

%Grabbing one column corresponding to a single signal%
Signal_Data = All_Signal_Data(:,Signal_Number);
Mean = Mean_Array(1,Signal_Number);
Maximum_Bound = Mean + Margin;
Minimum_Bound = Mean - Margin;

Signal_Data((Signal_Data > Minimum_Bound) & (Signal_Data < Maximum_Bound)) = Mean;
All_Signal_Data(:,Signal_Number) = Signal_Data;

end 


plot(Sample_Index,All_Signal_Data);
```

[image: Detecting Peaks/Noise Filtering]